# R how to use forecast function when I construct a ARMA model?

Tags: r, arima

```
library(forecast)
data(Nile,package="datasets")
train=Nile[1:50]##I want to use this to train model
test<-Nile[51:length(Nile)] 
m1<-auto.arima(Nile)
```

My question is that now I got a arima model, and how can I use this model combined with the old data(train) to forecast the value in test in dynamics. What I want is like in an OLS regression, I got a model, then I can use other data to test this model. Finally I can draw a picture.

Comment: Take a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68812/auto-arima-and-prediction

Comment: @zwep,thank you for your comments, I know feature of ARMA forecast. But what I want is that, for example, I use 2015-6-01-2015-9-01 to construct a model, and then I want to use this model to make an one-step forecast to forecast value in 2015-9-02. Then on 2015-9-02, I got the real value, and I want to use this real value combined with the model to forecast 2015-9-03.  Can I do this?

Comment: After reading some documentation.. it is as easy as calling

predict(m1,n.ahead = 3), where m1 is 'trained' on the train set... hence m1<-auto.arima(train)